# What happens when an item's durability drops to zero?

Tags: diablo-iii

What happens when an item's durability drops to zero?

Will the item be inactive like in WoW or will it be permanently destroyed like in Diablo 2?

Comment: Only ethereal items were permanently destroyed in Diablo 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't be permanently destroyed. It will just "break" and you can't use it anymore until you repair it.